# Как создать таблицу рекордов в игре?

Tags: c#, xml, разработка-игр

Я создал классическую игру змейка на C# с уровнями счетом и т.д., но я захотел сделать таблицу рекордов и у меня не получается, т.к. подсказали сделать на xml, но я с ним некогда не работал.

Как это можно реализовать?
А именно надо создать на 5 полей где будет написано имя и счет и при наличии большего счета заменить имя и счет.

Comment: Я бы использовал sqllite или JSON. XML все-таки это как пушкой по воробьям.

Comment: ну я так бы не сказал конечно  может и так но все-же мне будет удобней на xml (да, вот такой я человек)

Comment: Ну если XML, то [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/44238/) очень хорошая статья. Многое зависит от Ваших требований, которые будут расти с процессом разработки игрушки. Точный код или пример Вам тут смогут подсказать если выложите структуры записей Вашей программы

Comment: Статья очень занимательная но там ничего несказанно как заменить

Comment: Это была 1 часть а можете мне найти 2 часть?

Comment: По поводу добавления записи и создания файла разобрались. а вот удаление делается через [XmlNode.RemoveChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild(v=vs.110).aspx). В принципе ничего другого Вам не нужно будет

Answer (score 4):

Вот мой пример на [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/json-ru.html), если Вам подойдет конечно, использует [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) !! требует `System.Web.Extensions` !!

```
//Ваш класс записи рекорда
public class MyRecord
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public int Record { get; set;}
}
```

Как записать лист рекордов в текстовую переменную

```
//Запись в текстовую переменную forWriteToFile 
List<MyRecord> allRecords = new List<MyRecord>();
...
//Тут заполнение allRecords 
...
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = 
  new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string forWriteToFile = serializer.Serialize(allRecords );
```

Как прочитать лист рекордов из текстовой переменной

```
//Чтение из текстовой переменной forWriteToList
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = 
  new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<MyRecord> allRecords =  serializer.DeserializeObject<List<MyRecord>>(forWriteToList);
```

**UPD:** Пример редактирования

```
string JSON = Прочитать_Всё_Из_Файла("Рекорды.txt");//тут прочитали из файла в текстовую переменную JSON
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = 
  new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<MyRecord> allRecords = serializer.Deserialize<List<MyRecord>>(JSON);
allRecords.RemoveAt(1);//Удалили вторую запись
foreach(MyRecord record in allRecords)
  record.Record++;//Увеличили все рекорды на единицу 
allRecords.Add(new MyRecord(){Name="Вася", Record=1000});//Добавили запись
JSON = serializer.Serialize(allRecords); //Записали обратно в переменную JSON
Записать_В_Файл("Рекорды.txt", JSON);//Далее напишите запись текста в файл
```

Comment: А как изменить ?

Comment: Читаете, меняете или удаляете или добавляете в лист Ваши рекорды и записываете. Намноооого проще XML

Comment: Ну если XML, то на хабре очень хорошая статья. Многое зависит от Ваших требований, которые будут расти с процессом разработки игрушки. Точный код или пример Вам тут смогут подсказать если выложите структуры записей Вашей программы – Дмитрий Чистик 
     
Статья очень занимательная но там ничего несказанно как заменить – илья витюк   
     
Это была 1 часть а можете мне найти 2 часть?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала придется завести класс или структуру для хранения информации о игроке, например такую:

```
struct PlayerInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public int Score;
}
```

В простейшем случае будет достаточно структуры, однако ее в любой момент можно преобразовать в полноценный класс, а заодно и разобраться, чем структуры .NET отличаются от классов (тут уже не раз отвечали на этот вопрос).

Далее создаем хранилище для наших рекордов,

```
List<PlayerInfo>() recordTable = new List<PlayerInfo>();
```

прекрасно подойдет для этой цели.

В процессе работы программы, редактируем наш `List` как обычный массив, в начале программы загружаем в него значения из файла, в конце - выгружаем в файл.

Для хранения на диске, подойдет простой текстовый формат в котором одна строка хранит информацию об одном игроке, а значения разделены точкой с запятой, а ля `.csv`, например: `"Вася Пупкин;100500"`. В последствии можно доработать до полноценного `.csv` или более сложного формата. Не стоит сразу браться за XML, да и для такого простого случая он явно избыточен, либо автор что-то не договаривает =)

Остается реализовать сохранение и загрузку таблицы рекордов, в предложенном варианте с текстовым форматом, все делается построчными чтением и записью в файл, как это сделать есть в официальной документации на MSDN, на этом и многих других ресурсах, поэтому без подробностей.

Для удобства можно добавить в структуру/класс методы для удобного преобразования значений:

```
public void SetFromCsv(string csvStr)
{
    string[] fields = csvStr.Split(';');
    Name = fields[0];
    Score = int.Parse(fields[1]);
}

public string GetCsvString()
{
    return string.Format("{0};{1}", Name, Score);
}
```

Если все же очень хочется XML, то смотрите в сторону использования [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.100).aspx) и/или [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.100).aspx). Они имеют встроенные средства загрузки и сохранения xml-файлов простым указанием полного имени нужного файла. Однако замечу, что сортировать ноды внутри `XElement.Nodes`, в отличие от `List`, одной строчкой кода не получится, только руками, последовательно удаляя и создавая ноды в нужном порядке. Поэтому Использовать XML имеет смысл исключительно для хранения и загрузки, а все остальные действия выполнять над `List`.

Comment: надо создать ну лист или массив из 10 и чтоб можно было их заменять при необходимости + rdorn правильно говорит что я не договариваю. ОК. мне просто папа дал задание чтоб я сделал на xml. поэтому мне нужно на xml.

Comment: @ильявитюк тогда может сначала попросить папу рассказать что-то про XML и сериализацию, раз это его идея, а потом на основе новых знаний попробовать сделать? Потому что готовое решение конечно будет работать, но вы его не поймете, а от слепого копипаста знаний, увы, не прибавляется